# What is the difference between NSString* mystring and NSString *mystring

Tags: objective-c

I've come across several examples which declares classes in the header differently like

```
NSString* mystring;
```

or

```
NSString *mystring;
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Just remember, pick one and consistently use it throughout your project.  I don't care which, just be consistent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are three totally distinct lexical elements and the amount of whitespace in-between them is totally irrelevant. These are all equivalent in terms of what the compiler generates:

```
NSString*x;
NSString *x;
NSString* x;
NSString * x;
NSString                 *                 x;
NSString /* comment here */ * /* and another */ x;
```

I prefer the `NSString *x` variation since the pointer specifier belongs to the *variable,* not the type. By that, I mean that both of these:

```
int *x, y;
int* x, y;
```

create an integer pointer called `x` and an integer called `y`, *not* two integer pointers.

Comment: Thank you!  I was doing my head in over this - the book I'm learning from is not consistent in their usage and was confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. It's a matter of style.

In Objective-C, you can pretty much think of the star as part of the 'type' of the variable.

However, the compiler interprets the star as "treat this variable as a pointer to the declared type" (in this case NSString). Where it gets interesting is defining multiple variables at once:

```
NSString *myString, *yourString;
```

You must use the star on each variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is preference, and is useful if you declare multiple variables in the same line, viz

```
NSString* mystring1, mystring2;  // Misleading, mystring2 is not a *

NSString *mystring1, mystring2;  // Is more clear
```

Answer (score 0):

no difference, just coding style preference.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, it isn't even important to have space between them. You can even write `NSString*mystring`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no differences in reality.

Answer (score 0):

In C (and Objective-C, as a superset of C), placement of the `*` is merely a matter of style.

I'd recommend checking out the [relevant section](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Pointer_and_Reference_Expressions#Pointer_and_Reference_Expressions) from Google's style guide.

Answer (score 0):

None whatsoever - it's a personal preference as to whether you think...

1. Here comes a variable that's of type NSString pointer (`NSString* mystring`)

   or
2. Here comes a variable of type NSString that's a pointer (`NSString *mystring`)

...is more legible. That said, as long as you're consistent it isn't something you should loose sleep over.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. It's a matter of preference and style.

Here comes a variable that's of type `NSString` pointer `(NSString* mystring)`

Here comes a variable of type `NSString` that's a pointer `(NSString *mystring)`

Advantage of the first approach:

When coding to protocols, there's no issue with some variables having a star and some not. Example:

```
NSString*        _myString
id<SomeProtocol> _collaborator
```

versus (more confusing):

```
NString          *_myString
id<SomeProtocol> _collaborator
```

Drawback to this approach: (as pointed out)

```
//Only the first is a pointer. 
NSString* _myString, _anotherString
```

Modern OO languages (like Java) tend to discourage multiple variables on one line: http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc5.html#2991