# Does the pointer qualifier location in Objective-C matter?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between NSString* mystring and NSString *mystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231364/what-is-the-difference-between-nsstring-mystring-and-nsstring-mystring)

I believe it doesn't matter where you put the pointer qualifier (asterisk) and I thought I would ask the question to get clarification to know for sure.

Basically are all three of these shown below doing the same thing? Are they declaring a pointer to a UIColor, or are they each doing something subtlety different that would make it matter where you put the qualifier?

```
UIColor* myColorA;
UIColor * myColorB;
UIColor *myColorC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They all do exactly the same thing. You could even leave the whitespace out completely.