# NSString *string or NSString* string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between NSString* mystring and NSString *mystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231364/what-is-the-difference-between-nsstring-mystring-and-nsstring-mystring)

Should I put the * for a pointer with the variable or with the class?

i.e. 
NSString *string or NSString* string ?

The point for me isn't that both work anyway, but to understand which is correct syntactically and why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct both ways, means the same as well. Just be careful of doing stuff like this:

```
NSString *a,b;
```

Should be

```
NSString *a,*b;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's all the same but the correct way of writing it is :

```
NSString *string1;
```

If you want to declare multiple values on a same line, you will have to write :

```
        NSString *string1, *string2;

and not 

         NSString *string1, string2;

nor

         NSString* string1, string2;
```

Once you know that, you can do the way you like,  and if you miss, the compiler will alert you.